# Trying to fix fixed empty space in columns WordPress site

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working on a Wordpress site which is using CSS. I have defined 4 columns and tried to use the negative margin or padding, which reduces the space between the columns (This is what I want to do, shown in image 2), however it doesn't make the website responsive. I think this happens because all columns have fixed width. Is there any way I can reduce the empty space in the one of the columns?

Or maybe if I can reduce the width of one of the columns in Wordpress? [image 1, shows the empty space in a column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zziar.png)

[Image 2, is what needs to be done while being responsive as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqUOy.png)

Here's the CSS used for the page:

```
   body {
    margin: 0;
}

.content {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #525252;
}

.title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 32;
    line-height: 1.25;
    color: #161616;
}

.header {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

.details-title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12;
    line-height: 1.333;
    color: #525252;
}

.details-content {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14;
    line-height: 1.286;
    color: #161616;   
}

.caption {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12;
    line-height: 1.333;
    color: #525252;
}

.about-section {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16;
    line-height: 1.375;
    color: #161616;
}

.bx--text-area {
    height: 120px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.bx--row {
  min-height: 50px;
}

.bx--tile {
    padding: 0;
    height: 74px;
    margin: 1rem;
}

.bx--tile__content {
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
}

.bx--tile__content h2 {
    color: #161616;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.bx--tile__content p {
    color: #525252;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: .5rem 0 .75rem;
}
.space {
    margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

And [This is the Inspector View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XAd0.png)

Thank you

Comment: Could you please share the code, also the images are not clear and difficult to understand?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated, my apologies for the images, their resolution drops once I upload them here.